# Close or edit "Polearm with Reach, but without Heavy or Special property?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Polearm with Reach, but without Heavy or Special property?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/113874/polearm-with-reach-but-without-heavy-or-special-property)

This question does not seem answerable objectively in its current form. It seems to have attracted mainly opinion-based answers and may accumulate more if something is not done to clarify and refine the question.

Specifically, the OP seems to be asking us to adjudicate a homebrew weapon but without specifically giving us what exact solution / combination of properties they are proposing. So either is is opinion-based or it is a request for us to make something for them, or both.

Am I right here, or off-base?

Answer (score 3):

The question could use an edit for clarity and to better define their goals, but since we're working in a fairly narrow category (weapons and their relative balance) with fairly well defined edges, I don't think it is inherently opinion based.

Relevant text from the question:

> What I'm looking for must...
>
> ...be a **polearm.**
>
> ...have **Reach.**
>
> ...not be **Heavy** or **Special.**
>
> **Is such a weapon necessarily unbalanced?**

Given this, we have a fairly good framework to work from.. The only thing missing is the damage die, and any other relevant properties.